# How is a blank(s) treated in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C. I read that we can define a pointer like

```
int *pointername
```

However, I also read a piece of coding like the following

```
int * pointername
```

So my question is whether the blank is optional in this case?

More broadly speaking, could anyone summarize how blanks are used in C, please? For example, are two blanks the same as one blank? When is a blank necessary and when is it optional? ...

As pointed out in a comment, I am also asking for general question on treatment of blanks in C. So please do not close this question. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is the wrong place to ask (because we cannot teach you C in a few paragraphs). You need to read a good C programming book, and look at some good [C reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you suggest a good C programming book, please? Please know that I am new to C and previously had some experience in R. Thanks.

Comment: Well neither of those has the asterisk at the correct position. Yes, come at me!

Comment: Book recommendations are also off-topic. http://www.cprogramming.com/books/ritchie.html ; but I also recommend https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ (which is about programming, not about C)

Comment: @DeiDei: this is only your opinion (and I disagree with it). And it is a matter of style. From the standard [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) perspective, both piece of code are ok (but **both lack a final semicolon**)

Comment: @LateXFan: see also (and download) [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which is *very close* to the C11 standard.

Comment: I would've opted for re-openning. The question is not about which part of declaration an asterisk is but about treatment of white-space in C.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Second that.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What about the more general question on blanks?

Comment: @LaTeXFan Perhaps you could stress that the case of the treatment of `*` in declarations is just one example. Other interesting cases might be empty macro definitions, e.g. `#define BLANK`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Could you edit my question, please? I am not aware of empty macro. I am only getting started with C. Thank you.